# how to get data from an api and display one item at a time (i.e. one item per second) in angular 9?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've an angular service that returns an array of items fetched from a server.

```
// get-item.service.ts file

getItem()

// this getItem() is a method inside my service.
// this method returns an array of JSON Objects
```

```
// component.ts file
items = []

constructor(private getItemsService: getItemsService)

ngOnInit() {
this.getItemsService.getItem().subscribe(items => {

this.items = items

}
```

But inside my component I just want to push only one item from the fetched array at a time in every 1 sec.

```
//component.html file

<li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li>
```

So that in my template only one item appear at a time (i.e. one item per second).

Comment: Can you please describe your use case with more details? Are you trying to call your API every 1 sec, or to call it once and display the items one by one at every second?

Comment: call it once. cause the method in the service returns an array of objects.

& I just want to render only one item in every second inside my template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/zip) that only emits Nth item when all its source observables have emitted Nth item:

```
const oneItem$ = zip(interval(1000), items$.pipe(concatAll())),
```

`concatAll` will turn `Observable<Item[]>` into  `Observable<Item>` so it'll unpack the array and reemit each item as a separate emission.

You can also use `timer(0, 1000)` instead of `interval` if you don't want to initial 1s delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sometime similar to this (not tested):

(Sorry that I’m replying on my phone so I’m not sure if I have made any typo)

```
class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public item$: Observable<T>;
  private items: T[];
  private subscriptions: Subscription[];

  constructor(...) {
    this.items = [];
    this.subscriptions = [];
    this.item$ = interval(1000).pipe(
      filter(() => this.items.length > 0),
      map(() => this.items.shift())
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.service.getItems().subscribe(items => {
        this.items = items;
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    for(const s of this.subscriptions) {
      s.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<li>{{item$ | async}}</li>
```

Comment: You can even change this.items into an observable and have this.item$ to emit its value sourcing from both the interval observable and the this.items observable.

Comment: What’re your requirements that the above solution does not answer to?

Comment: I believe we should keep our dicussion here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You could define an separate variable to render in the template. And change it's value every one second to the values in the `items` array. Try the following

Component

```js
items = [];
itemToRender: any;

constructor(private getItemsService: getItemsService)

ngOnInit() {
  this.getItemsService.getItem().subscribe(items => {
    this.items = items;
    this.renderItemsSequentially();
  });
}

private renderItemsSequentially() {
  let i = 0;
  let length = this.items.length - 1;
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (i < length) {
      this.itemToRender = this.items[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      delete this.itemToRender;
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

It uses `setInterval()` method to loop the array every one second. You could remove `delete this.itemToRender;` if you want the element to persist in the DOM after all the items have been displayed. If not the element will be removed after all the items are looped over.

And render the `itemToRender` variable in the template. I am using the `json` pipe because you mentioned `items` is a list of objects.

```html
<div *ngIf="itemToRender">Current item: {{ itemToRender | json }}</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file-nt5ejx)

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom operator for that (as an alternative to all the good solutions presented in the other answers => take a look at this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-a-60829635-6433166?file=index.ts)):

```js
/**
 * This operator expects an array of anything and emits
 *   each element of the array at a given pace determined by
 *   a parameter that represents the interval between emissions,
 *   in ms

 * @param {n} the interval between emissions in ms 
 */
const pace = <T = number>(n: number) => <T>(
  source: Observable<Array<T>>
) => {
  return source.pipe(
    switchMap((value: Array<T>) => {
      return new Observable<T>(subscriber => {
        let counter = value.length;
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          const v = value[value.length - counter];
          if (counter) {
            subscriber.next(v);
            counter--;
          } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            subscriber.complete();
          }
        }, n);
      });
    })
  );
};

// emit array as single value and apply the pace operator
const arraySource = of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).pipe(pace(2000));

// output: 1,2,3,4,5 with interval of 2 seconds between the emissions
const subscribe = arraySource.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is map the array elements (items) into individual observables creating a second order observable. You can use the index of the array in combination with `delay` rxjs operator to give different delays to each element.

```
// component.ts file

$items = this.getItemsService.getItem().pipe(
  map(items => items.map((item, i) => of(item).pipe(delay(i * 1000))))
)
```

Then, in your template, you can use the `async` to subscribe to both the `$items` array and each individual `$item`.

```
//component.html file

<li *ngFor="let $item of $items | async">{{ $item | async }}</li>
```